# React - Add data to a list

Tags: reactjs

I have two mapped lists of items. When I click on the `div` using `onClick={(e) => handleCheckClick(ele)}` I want to display the clicked items in a table but I am getting errors.

`handleCheckClick` function

```
 function handleCheckClick(ele) {
 if (trayItems?.length > 0) {
     settrayItems(
       trayItems.map((item) => {
         return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
       })
     );
   } else {
     settrayItems([...trayItems, ele]);
   }
 }
```

How I map two list items into `div`

```
<div>
{
    item && item.filter((person) => person.status == "0").map((ele) => {
        return (
            <div
                className="newmo-card"
                style={styles.innerbox}
                onClick={(e) => handleCheckClick(ele)}>
                {`${ele.item}`}
                <br />
                <span> {`${ele.total_price}`}</span>
            </div>

        );
    })
}
</div>
<Tray trayItems2={trayItems} trayItems1={trayPrice} />
```

Table of clicked items:

```
  function Tray({ trayItems }) {
    return (
      <>
      <div className="foo">
        <table>
          {trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{ele.item}</td>
                      <td>{ele.price}</td>
                      <td>{ele.quantity}</td>
                    </tr>
         
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-rain-47cico) so you can identify the issue

Comment: You must provide your error. Plus, your provided codes are missing too much, e.g, where `count` come from at `<td>{count}</td>` and missing some `}` token.

Comment: i have updated the question actuly i dont have a logic for {count} it would be nice if u can help with that @HuyPham

Comment: here also can u pls share your item data.

Comment: [ {
      "user_id": 1,
        "item": "biriani",
        "price": "50",
        "selling_price": "60",
        "created_at": "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-15T06:17:20.000000Z",
        "tax": "5%",
        "total_price": "80",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
      "user_id": 5,
      "item": "alfarm",
       "price": "100",
        "selling_price": "120",
        "created_at": "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
        "tax": "5%",
        "total_price": "140",
        "status": 0
    },
]

Comment: @Kantivekariya this is the data i get if i console.log(item)

Comment: ```{`${ele.item}`}``` what's this and why dont you just write ```{ele.item}``` ?

Comment: both are same  i just got the code in that format so i did not change @PapaXVII can u help with the question

Comment: @menucd you should include in the question what errors are you getting, I can't see errors on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sharing the significant parts of the code here. Check the code sandbox for the working code.

Here are the significant changes:

1. Moved the `Tray` definition outside the `App` component. Defining a component inside another component is almost always a bad idea. You won't have an issue because you don't have any state in `Tray`. If you had any state, it would have been reset to the initial value on every render of `App`.
2. Changed the `trayItems` to an object. The keys are the `id`s of each item. And the value is an object that contains the name, quantity, and price.
3. We'll only render the item in the `Tray` if the quantity is greater than `0`.
4. Changed the `handleCheckClick` to handle the object.

```
function Tray({ trayItems }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="foo">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {Object.entries(trayItems)
              .filter(([, v]) => v.quantity > 0)
              .map(([k, v]) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={k}>
                    <td>{v.item}</td>
                    <td>{v.price}</td>
                    <td>{v.quantity}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [trayItems, setTrayItems] = useState(
    item.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [curr.user_id]: { item: curr.item, quantity: 0, price: curr.price }
      };
    }, {})
  );

  const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
    setTrayItems((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [ele.user_id]: {
          ...prev[ele.user_id],
          quantity: prev[ele.user_id].quantity + 1
        }
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {item &&
          item
            .filter((person) => person.status === 0)
            .map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="newmo-card"
                  onClick={() => handleCheckClick(ele)}
                >
                  {`${ele.item}`}
                  <br />
                  <span> {`${ele.total_price}`}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
      <Tray trayItems={trayItems} />
    </>
  );
```

[image: Edit intelligent-brahmagupta-qchf18]

Answer (score 0):

here why do you manage two diff states? pls check the working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-khayyam-get5ln).

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const item = [
  {
    user_id: 1,
    item: "biriani",
    price: "50",
    selling_price: "60",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T06:17:20.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 1,
    quantity: 0

  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    item: "alfarm",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [trayItems, settrayItems] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
    if (trayItems?.length > 0) {
      settrayItems(trayItems.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
      }))
    } else {
      settrayItems([...trayItems, ele]);
    }
  };

  function Tray({ trayItems }) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="foo">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{ele.item}</td>
                      <td>{ele.price}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {item &&
          item
            .filter((person) => person.status === 0)
            .map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="newmo-card"
                  onClick={() => handleCheckClick(ele)}
                >
                  {`${ele.item}`}
                  <br />
                  <span> {`${ele.total_price}`}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
      <Tray trayItems={trayItems} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: ok but when i click on a item  more than 1s lets say biriani i dont want it to be added again insted i want the count of birinani to increse

Comment: so here you need to add the quantity field in the items array of objects.

Comment: yes can u help me with the logic

Comment: sure let me update the above code.

Comment: @menucd pls check i updated increment logic

Comment: for some reason its not working ur codesand box also is not working

Comment: @menucd can u pls compare above code and codesandbox I think sandbox is not updated.

Comment: i used the above code but its works only if there is 1 data in items array  i have created a sandbox based on ur answer pls check so u can undersand  https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-rain-47cico

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning that `<td> and <tr> cannot appear as a child of <table>`.

Wrap body with `<body>` tag and use `<tr>` tag to represent each row.

```
<div className="foo">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {trayItems2.length === trayItems1.length &&
        trayItems2.map((ele, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={ele}>
              <td>{ele}</td>
              <td>{trayItems1[index]}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Because of using `trayItems1[index]` to get map items in another array so you need to pre-check them. You need to refine it for tighter conditions.

Also, define unique key props for each child element in `<table>`. Here I simply use `key={ele}`. And using two arrays is redundant. Merge them could be easier.

Comment: it's occurring bcz you can not add `<tbody>` inside your `<table>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The (find) method was added to compare the id with the trayItems array, >using the selection id, inside with the (map) method, we
>    validate again >using ternary, if it is equal it increases, if not, it
>    is the same, now yes >selected value is not found, create a new one
>    and add element quantity = 1
> 2. method (map) was created inside to validate the selection using the  >ternary is subtracted, valid up to 1, but if we click again, we delete it, >the button for the **decre()** function is activated by
>    **ele.quantity**

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-currying-nfmxfm?file=/src/App.js

```
  export default function App() {
      const [trayItems, settrayItems] = useState([]);
     
  
    // 1.
  const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
    const dupe = trayItems.find((obj) => obj.user_id === ele.user_id);

    settrayItems(
      dupe
        ? trayItems.map((stat) =>
            stat.user_id === ele.user_id
              ? { ...stat, quantity: stat.quantity + 1 }
              : stat
          )
        : [...trayItems, { ...ele, quantity: (ele.quantity = 1) }]
    );
  };
   

  // 2.
const decre = (idd) => {
    settrayItems(
      trayItems.map((stat) =>
        stat.user_id === idd
          ? stat.quantity !== 1
            ? {
                ...stat,
                quantity:
                  stat.quantity > 1 ? stat.quantity - 1 : (stat.quantity = 1)
              }
            : trayItems.filter((e) => e.id !== idd)
          : stat
      )
    );
  };

  function Tray({ trayItems }) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="foo">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {trayItems &&
                trayItems.map((ele, index) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{ele.item}</td>
                      <td>{ele.price}</td>
                      <td onClick={() => decre(ele.user_id)>{ele.quantity}</td>
              
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {item &&
          item
            .filter((person) => person.status === 0)
            .map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={index}
                  className="newmo-card"
                  onClick={() => handleCheckClick(ele)}
                >
                  {`${ele.item}`}
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <span> {`${ele.price}`}</span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
      </div>
      <Tray trayItems={trayItems} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: @jakson ur answer is alsmost correct but here there are 2 things missing 1.the qty doesnot increse onlly to 1  when cliked on item i have to clik on + sign  to increse  and 2nd quantiy when dicreserd only goes until 1 i want to remove the item when its zero

Comment: @menucd thanks for the comments I hope this is your answer greetings

Answer (score 0):

There is something issue that in your code

`handleCheckClick` function

```
const handleCheckClick = (ele) => {
let index = trayItems.findIndex((item) => item.user_id === ele.user_id);
if (index >= 0) {
  let newItems = trayItems;
  let item = trayItems.find((item) => item.user_id === ele.user_id);
  item = { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };

  newItems.splice(index, 1, item);

  settrayItems([...newItems]);
} else {
  settrayItems([...trayItems, ele]);
}
};
```

For more details Check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-gwen-dyzuvg?file=/src/dash.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code was how you handled the click function and the modification of state subsequently.

1. Removed duplicate products (having same id)

```
const items = [
  {
    user_id: 1,
    item: "biriani",
    price: "50",
    selling_price: "60",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:12:58.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T14:05:45.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    item: "burger",
    price: "80",
    selling_price: "80",
    created_at: "2022-08-29T10:21:13.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-14T04:46:36.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "100",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 3,
    item: "alfarm",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T11:06:23.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 4,
    item: "sandwich",
    price: "100",
    selling_price: "120",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-14T04:46:37.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "140",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 5,
    item: "pizza",
    price: "200",
    selling_price: "220",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "240",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 6,
    item: "chicken sadwich",
    price: "200",
    selling_price: "220",
    created_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-07T13:27:33.000000Z",
    tax: "5",
    total_price: "250",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    user_id: 7,
    item: "sharja shake",
    price: "60",
    selling_price: "70",
    created_at: "2022-09-09T06:58:45.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-09-15T14:05:53.000000Z",
    tax: "5%",
    total_price: "80",
    status: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }
];
```

2. Kept single variable in state for products & updated state accordingly

```
export default function App() {
  const [trayItems, setTrayItems] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckClick = (item) => {
    const itemExists = trayItems.findIndex((ite) => ite.user_id === item.user_id) !== -1;
    if (itemExists) {
      setTrayItems(
        trayItems.map((prod) => ({
          ...prod,
          quantity:
            prod.user_id === item.user_id ? prod.quantity + 1 : prod.quantity
        }))
      );
    } else {
      setTrayItems([...trayItems, { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        {items
          ?.filter((item) => item.status === 0)
          ?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tbody
                key={index}
                onClick={() => handleCheckClick(item)}
              >
                <td>{item.item}</td>
                <td>{item.total_price}</td>
              </tbody>
            );
          })}
      </table>
      <Tray trayItems={trayItems} />
    </>
  );
}
```

3. Moved the child component outside parent.

```
const Tray = ({ trayItems }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
          {trayItems?.map((ele, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{ele.item}</td>
              <td>{ele.price}</td>
              <td>{ele.quantity}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```